# How to make FLAT grass in particle system, without template multiplying

Tags: modifiers, particles, geometry, hair, procedural

i achieved effect of flat grass with particle system, and can not replicate it, even with Blender file

Could anyone tell me, how particle grass is flat, and not round?

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found out, that long plane can somehow stretch the hair on Y-axis, so it is not round anymore. This results in "Flat" effect.

So method for cool grass in your scene:

1. Resize scene, make it smaller, but only on Y-axis.
2. Add simple grass using particles.
3. Make grass with high diameter root, and small tip.
4. Resize back on Y-axis, this should flatten your grass.
5. Adjust diameter root.

[image]